# GeckoFX Print PDF C#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, gecko, geckofx

I need help. you want to use GeckoFX browser to generate and display. however, the pdf viewer is in gecko. how can I print the displayed pdf on the specified printer?

Now I use this method, but it is too slow ...

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(www, @"C:\Users\Radek\Documents\dpd.pdf");
}
www = null;
PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
PdfFilePrinter printer = new PdfFilePrinter(@"C:\Users\Radek\Documents\dpd.pdf", comboBox2.Text);
try
{
    printer.Print();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433937/how-to-print-geckowebbrowser-to-default-printer

Comment: unfortunately this option does not work for me :(